# Group id's based on condition on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef  
2400614     May-2015        2297544     0           
2400614     June-2015       2297544     0            
2400614     July-2015       2297544     0               
2400614     August-2015     2297544     0               
2400614     September-2015  2297544     0               
2400614     October-2015    2297544     0               
2400614     November-2015   2297544     0           
2400614     December-2015   2297544     0          
2400614     January-2016    2297544     1        
2400614     February-2016   2297544     1           
2400614     March-2016      2297544     1         

3400624     May-2016        2597531     0           
3400624     June-2016       2597531     0         
3400624     July-2016       2597531     0          
3400624     August-2016     2597531     1           
3400624     September-2016  2597531     1           

2400133     February-2016   4597531     0           
2400133     March-2016      4597531     0               
2400133     April-2016      4597531     0         
2400133     May-2016        4597531     0               
2400133     June-2016       4597531     0           
2400133     July-2016       4597531     0           
2400133     August-2016     4597531     1           
2400133     September-2016  4597531     1               
2400133     October-2016    4597531     1               
2400133     November-2016   4597531     1               
2400133     December-2016   4597531     1               
2400133     January-2017    4597531     1           
2400133     February-2017   4597531     1               
2400133     March-2017      4597531     1           
2400133     April-2017      4597531     1         
2400133     May-2017        4597531     1
```

I should capture the Hotel_id, where each id should have the minimum count of three 0's and 1's in the Chef_is_masterchef column and neglect other Hotel_id which doesn't meet the condition.

After performing the required operation, It looks something like this

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef  
2400614     May-2015        2297544     0           
2400614     June-2015       2297544     0            
2400614     July-2015       2297544     0               
2400614     August-2015     2297544     0               
2400614     September-2015  2297544     0               
2400614     October-2015    2297544     0               
2400614     November-2015   2297544     0           
2400614     December-2015   2297544     0          
2400614     January-2016    2297544     1        
2400614     February-2016   2297544     1           
2400614     March-2016      2297544     1         
        

2400133     February-2016   4597531     0           
2400133     March-2016      4597531     0               
2400133     April-2016      4597531     0         
2400133     May-2016        4597531     0               
2400133     June-2016       4597531     0           
2400133     July-2016       4597531     0           
2400133     August-2016     4597531     1           
2400133     September-2016  4597531     1               
2400133     October-2016    4597531     1               
2400133     November-2016   4597531     1               
2400133     December-2016   4597531     1               
2400133     January-2017    4597531     1           
2400133     February-2017   4597531     1               
2400133     March-2017      4597531     1           
2400133     April-2017      4597531     1         
2400133     May-2017        4597531     1
```

So in the above data frame, one id got deleted.

Also, I have to repeat the same process to get another data frame where each Hotel_id should have the minimum count of six 0's and 1's in the Chef_is_masterchef column and neglect other Hotel_id which doesn't meet the condition.

In this case, two ids get deleted and look something like this,

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef 
2400133     February-2016   4597531     0           
2400133     March-2016      4597531     0               
2400133     April-2016      4597531     0         
2400133     May-2016        4597531     0               
2400133     June-2016       4597531     0           
2400133     July-2016       4597531     0           
2400133     August-2016     4597531     1           
2400133     September-2016  4597531     1               
2400133     October-2016    4597531     1               
2400133     November-2016   4597531     1               
2400133     December-2016   4597531     1               
2400133     January-2017    4597531     1           
2400133     February-2017   4597531     1               
2400133     March-2017      4597531     1           
2400133     April-2017      4597531     1         
2400133     May-2017        4597531     1
```

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions if only `0` and `1` values in column `Chef_is_masterchef`:

First count values per groups by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and filter if both columns has more or equal values by `N` by [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) for both columns by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and then pass index values which match both conditions to [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
N = 3
s = pd.crosstab(df['Hotel_id'], df['Chef_is_masterchef']).ge(N).all(1)

df1 = df[df['Hotel_id'].isin(s.index[s])]
```

Or you can create new column for test `0` values called `zeros` and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for count `0` and `1` values per groups, output is `mask` passed to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3
mask = (df.assign(zeros=df['Chef_is_masterchef'].eq(0))
          .groupby('Hotel_id')[['Chef_is_masterchef', 'zeros']]
          .transform('sum')
          .ge(N)
          .all(axis=1))
df1 = df[mask]
```

---

```
print (df1)
    Hotel_id      Month_Year  Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef
0    2400614        May-2015  2297544                   0
1    2400614       June-2015  2297544                   0
2    2400614       July-2015  2297544                   0
3    2400614     August-2015  2297544                   0
4    2400614  September-2015  2297544                   0
5    2400614    October-2015  2297544                   0
6    2400614   November-2015  2297544                   0
7    2400614   December-2015  2297544                   0
8    2400614    January-2016  2297544                   1
9    2400614   February-2016  2297544                   1
10   2400614      March-2016  2297544                   1
16   2400133   February-2016  4597531                   0
17   2400133      March-2016  4597531                   0
18   2400133      April-2016  4597531                   0
19   2400133        May-2016  4597531                   0
20   2400133       June-2016  4597531                   0
21   2400133       July-2016  4597531                   0
22   2400133     August-2016  4597531                   1
23   2400133  September-2016  4597531                   1
24   2400133    October-2016  4597531                   1
25   2400133   November-2016  4597531                   1
26   2400133   December-2016  4597531                   1
27   2400133    January-2017  4597531                   1
28   2400133   February-2017  4597531                   1
29   2400133      March-2017  4597531                   1
30   2400133      April-2017  4597531                   1
31   2400133        May-2017  4597531                   1
```

---

```
N = 6
mask = (df.assign(zeros=df['Chef_is_masterchef'].eq(0))
          .groupby('Hotel_id')[['Chef_is_masterchef', 'zeros']]
          .transform('sum')
          .ge(N)
          .all(axis=1))
df2 = df[mask]
print (df2)
    Hotel_id      Month_Year  Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef
16   2400133   February-2016  4597531                   0
17   2400133      March-2016  4597531                   0
18   2400133      April-2016  4597531                   0
19   2400133        May-2016  4597531                   0
20   2400133       June-2016  4597531                   0
21   2400133       July-2016  4597531                   0
22   2400133     August-2016  4597531                   1
23   2400133  September-2016  4597531                   1
24   2400133    October-2016  4597531                   1
25   2400133   November-2016  4597531                   1
26   2400133   December-2016  4597531                   1
27   2400133    January-2017  4597531                   1
28   2400133   February-2017  4597531                   1
29   2400133      March-2017  4597531                   1
30   2400133      April-2017  4597531                   1
31   2400133        May-2017  4597531                   1
```

If possible some another values like `0`and `1` is possible use:

```
N = 3
mask = (df.assign(zeros= df['Chef_is_masterchef'].eq(0),
                  ones = df['Chef_is_masterchef'].eq(1))
          .groupby('Hotel_id')[['ones', 'zeros']]
          .transform('sum')
          .ge(N)
          .all(axis=1))

df1 = df[mask]
```

Comment: Can you please answer to my recent question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846137/how-to-select-rows-based-on-conditions-for-each-id) which is almost related to this question

Comment: @Shashidhar R Sorry, now I am offline, weekend. In Tuesday is holiday in Slovakia, so my weekend time is longer, to Wednesday. So offline few days, on phone only.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I will be waiting for your reply.
 Happy long weekend.