# How to generate values based on conditions for new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame:

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef  Transition
2400188     February-2018   4597566     1                    0
2400188     March-2018      4597566     1                    0
2400188     April-2018      4597566     1                    0
2400188     May-2018        4597566     1                    0
2400188     June-2018       4597566     1                    0
2400188     July-2018       4597566     1                    0
2400188     August-2018     4597566     1                    0
2400188     September-2018  4597566     0                    1
2400188     October-2018    4597566     0                    0
2400188     November-2018   4597566     0                    0
2400188     December-2018   4597566     0                    0
2400188     January-2019    4597566     0                    0
2400188     February-2019   4597566     0                    0
2400188     March-2019      4597566     0                    0
2400188     April-2019      4597566     0                    0
2400188     May-2019        4597566     0                    0


2400614     May-2015        2297544     0                    0
2400614     June-2015       2297544     0                    0
2400614     July-2015       2297544     0                    0
2400614     August-2015     2297544     0                    0
2400614     September-2015  2297544     0                    0
2400614     October-2015    2297544     0                    0
2400614     November-2015   2297544     0                    0
2400614     December-2015   2297544     0                    0
2400614     January-2016    2297544     1                    1
2400614     February-2016   2297544     1                    0
2400614     March-2016      2297544     1                    0

3400624     May-2016        2597531     0                    0
3400624     June-2016       2597531     0                    0
3400624     July-2016       2597531     0                    0
3400624     August-2016     2597531     1                    1

2400133     February-2016   4597531     0                    0
2400133     March-2016      4597531     0                    0
2400133     April-2016      4597531     0                    0
2400133     May-2016        4597531     0                    0
2400133     June-2016       4597531     0                    0
2400133     July-2016       4597531     0                    0
2400133     August-2016     4597531     1                    1
2400133     September-2016  4597531     1                    0
2400133     October-2016    4597531     1                    0
2400133     November-2016   4597531     1                    0
2400133     December-2016   4597531     1                    0
2400133     January-2017    4597531     1                    0
2400133     February-2017   4597531     1                    0
2400133     March-2017      4597531     1                    0
2400133     April-2017      4597531     1                    0
2400133     May-2017        4597531     1                    0
```

When the transition takes place from **0 to 1** or **1 to 0** in the **Chef_is_Masterchef** column, this transition is indicated in the **Transition** column as **1**.

Actually, I thought of creating another column (named as "**Var**") where the values will be filled as mentioned below for the original data frame,

**Expected data frame:**

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef  Transition  Var
2400188     February-2018   4597566     1                    0       -7
2400188     March-2018      4597566     1                    0       -6
2400188     April-2018      4597566     1                    0       -5
2400188     May-2018        4597566     1                    0       -4
2400188     June-2018       4597566     1                    0       -3
2400188     July-2018       4597566     1                    0       -2
2400188     August-2018     4597566     1                    0       -1
2400188     September-2018  4597566     0                    1        0
2400188     October-2018    4597566     0                    0        1
2400188     November-2018   4597566     0                    0        2
2400188     December-2018   4597566     0                    0        3
2400188     January-2019    4597566     0                    0        4
2400188     February-2019   4597566     0                    0        5
2400188     March-2019      4597566     0                    0        6
2400188     April-2019      4597566     0                    0        7
2400188     May-2019        4597566     0                    0        8

2400614     May-2015        2297544     0                    0       -8
2400614     June-2015       2297544     0                    0       -7
2400614     July-2015       2297544     0                    0       -6
2400614     August-2015     2297544     0                    0       -5
2400614     September-2015  2297544     0                    0       -4
2400614     October-2015    2297544     0                    0       -3
2400614     November-2015   2297544     0                    0       -2
2400614     December-2015   2297544     0                    0       -1
2400614     January-2016    2297544     1                    1        0
2400614     February-2016   2297544     1                    0        1
2400614     March-2016      2297544     1                    0        2

3400624     May-2016        2597531     0                    0       -3
3400624     June-2016       2597531     0                    0       -2
3400624     July-2016       2597531     0                    0       -1
3400624     August-2016     2597531     1                    1        0

2400133     February-2016   4597531     0                    0       -6
2400133     March-2016      4597531     0                    0       -5
2400133     April-2016      4597531     0                    0       -4
2400133     May-2016        4597531     0                    0       -3
2400133     June-2016       4597531     0                    0       -2
2400133     July-2016       4597531     0                    0       -1
2400133     August-2016     4597531     1                    1        0
2400133     September-2016  4597531     1                    0        1
2400133     October-2016    4597531     1                    0        2
2400133     November-2016   4597531     1                    0        3
2400133     December-2016   4597531     1                    0        4
2400133     January-2017    4597531     1                    0        5
2400133     February-2017   4597531     1                    0        6
2400133     March-2017      4597531     1                    0        7
2400133     April-2017      4597531     1                    0        8
2400133     May-2017        4597531     1                    0        9
```

If observed, at the point of transition in the **Var** column I am giving the value as zero and for the rows before and after I am maintaining the corresponding integer values.

**But after using the below code I had an issue in the Var column,**

```
s = df['Chef_is_masterchef'].eq(0).groupby(df['Chef_Id']).transform('sum')
df['var'] = df.groupby('Chef_Id').cumcount().sub(s)
```

**Output from the above code**:

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef  Transition  Var
2400188     February-2018   4597566     1                    0       -9
2400188     March-2018      4597566     1                    0       -8
2400188     April-2018      4597566     1                    0       -7
2400188     May-2018        4597566     1                    0       -6
2400188     June-2018       4597566     1                    0       -5
2400188     July-2018       4597566     1                    0       -4
2400188     August-2018     4597566     1                    0       -3
2400188     September-2018  4597566     0                    1       -2
2400188     October-2018    4597566     0                    0       -1
2400188     November-2018   4597566     0                    0        0
2400188     December-2018   4597566     0                    0        1
2400188     January-2019    4597566     0                    0        2
2400188     February-2019   4597566     0                    0        3
2400188     March-2019      4597566     0                    0        4
2400188     April-2019      4597566     0                    0        5
2400188     May-2019        4597566     0                    0        6

2400614     May-2015        2297544     0                    0       -8
2400614     June-2015       2297544     0                    0       -7
2400614     July-2015       2297544     0                    0       -6
2400614     August-2015     2297544     0                    0       -5
2400614     September-2015  2297544     0                    0       -4
2400614     October-2015    2297544     0                    0       -3
2400614     November-2015   2297544     0                    0       -2
2400614     December-2015   2297544     0                    0       -1
2400614     January-2016    2297544     1                    1        0
2400614     February-2016   2297544     1                    0        1
2400614     March-2016      2297544     1                    0        2

3400624     May-2016        2597531     0                    0       -3
3400624     June-2016       2597531     0                    0       -2
3400624     July-2016       2597531     0                    0       -1
3400624     August-2016     2597531     1                    1        0

2400133     February-2016   4597531     0                    0       -6
2400133     March-2016      4597531     0                    0       -5
2400133     April-2016      4597531     0                    0       -4
2400133     May-2016        4597531     0                    0       -3
2400133     June-2016       4597531     0                    0       -2
2400133     July-2016       4597531     0                    0       -1
2400133     August-2016     4597531     1                    1        0
2400133     September-2016  4597531     1                    0        1
2400133     October-2016    4597531     1                    0        2
2400133     November-2016   4597531     1                    0        3
2400133     December-2016   4597531     1                    0        4
2400133     January-2017    4597531     1                    0        5
2400133     February-2017   4597531     1                    0        6
2400133     March-2017      4597531     1                    0        7
2400133     April-2017      4597531     1                    0        8
2400133     May-2017        4597531     1                    0        9
```

If Observed, for the Chef_Id = 4597566 you can see at the point of transition the value is different instead of zero in the Var column.

This creates a problem because, at the point of transition, I have to select rows including up to 3 months before and 2 months after for each id. Also at the point of transition, I have to select rows including up to 6 months before and 5 months after for each id using the below code:

```
df1 = df[df['var'].between(-3, 2)]
print (df1)

df2 = df[df['var'].between(-6, 5)]
print (df2)
```

So please let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem occurs when `Chef_is_masterchef` starts with `1` and ends with `0`. You would need to filterout these cases and use `s = df['Chef_is_masterchef'].eq(1) ...` on them instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform` with `numpy.arange` and `numpy.argmax`:

```
df["Var"] = df.groupby("Chef_Id")["Transition"].transform(lambda x: np.arange(x.size) - np.argmax(x))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Hotel_id      Month_Year  Chef_Id  Chef_is_masterchef  Transition  Var
0    2400188   February-2018  4597566                   1           0   -7
1    2400188      March-2018  4597566                   1           0   -6
2    2400188      April-2018  4597566                   1           0   -5
3    2400188        May-2018  4597566                   1           0   -4
4    2400188       June-2018  4597566                   1           0   -3
5    2400188       July-2018  4597566                   1           0   -2
6    2400188     August-2018  4597566                   1           0   -1
7    2400188  September-2018  4597566                   0           1    0
8    2400188    October-2018  4597566                   0           0    1
9    2400188   November-2018  4597566                   0           0    2
10   2400188   December-2018  4597566                   0           0    3
11   2400188    January-2019  4597566                   0           0    4
12   2400188   February-2019  4597566                   0           0    5
13   2400188      March-2019  4597566                   0           0    6
14   2400188      April-2019  4597566                   0           0    7
15   2400188        May-2019  4597566                   0           0    8
16   2400614        May-2015  2297544                   0           0   -8
17   2400614       June-2015  2297544                   0           0   -7
18   2400614       July-2015  2297544                   0           0   -6
19   2400614     August-2015  2297544                   0           0   -5
20   2400614  September-2015  2297544                   0           0   -4
21   2400614    October-2015  2297544                   0           0   -3
22   2400614   November-2015  2297544                   0           0   -2
23   2400614   December-2015  2297544                   0           0   -1
24   2400614    January-2016  2297544                   1           1    0
25   2400614   February-2016  2297544                   1           0    1
26   2400614      March-2016  2297544                   1           0    2
27   3400624        May-2016  2597531                   0           0   -3
28   3400624       June-2016  2597531                   0           0   -2
29   3400624       July-2016  2597531                   0           0   -1
30   3400624     August-2016  2597531                   1           1    0
31   2400133   February-2016  4597531                   0           0   -6
32   2400133      March-2016  4597531                   0           0   -5
33   2400133      April-2016  4597531                   0           0   -4
34   2400133        May-2016  4597531                   0           0   -3
35   2400133       June-2016  4597531                   0           0   -2
36   2400133       July-2016  4597531                   0           0   -1
37   2400133     August-2016  4597531                   1           1    0
38   2400133  September-2016  4597531                   1           0    1
39   2400133    October-2016  4597531                   1           0    2
40   2400133   November-2016  4597531                   1           0    3
41   2400133   December-2016  4597531                   1           0    4
42   2400133    January-2017  4597531                   1           0    5
43   2400133   February-2017  4597531                   1           0    6
44   2400133      March-2017  4597531                   1           0    7
45   2400133      April-2017  4597531                   1           0    8
46   2400133        May-2017  4597531                   1           0    9
```